# How can I make a named query with IN actually work?

Tags: hibernate, collections, jboss, jpa-2.0

```
class X {
Y y; // manyToOne
}
class Y {
Long id;
}
```

```
@NamedQuery(name = "someName", query = "from X where y.id in :ids")
```

I have public, table, entity and all other things on the Entities but I didn't wrote them here.

```
TypedQuery<X> query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("someName", X.class);
query.setParameter("ids", someListOfLongs); // HERE I GET THE ERROR
queryFinal.getResultList();
```

`Parameter value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@90d0bf] was not matching type [java.lang.Long]`

I tried with or without (), I changed the version of Hibernate-Core to 3.6.4 (from JBoss 6.0.0.Final), otherwise if I wrote `in :ids` without () I'd got an error.

Please Help.

`The IN always worked, the problem was that List<Long> wasn't actually List<Long> was List<Object[]>. Thanks`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also use JBoss AS 6 and this exact construct, but it just works.

This is an example of a query:

```
<named-query name="Item.getByItemIDs">
    <query>
        SELECT
            i
        FROM
            Item i
        WHERE
            i.ID in (:itemsIDs)
    </query>
</named-query>
```

And of a class using it:

```
@Override
public List<Item> getByItemIDs(List<Long> itemIDs) {
    return entityManager.createNamedQuery("Item.getByItemIDs", Item.class)
                        .setParameter("itemIDs", itemIDs)
                        .getResultList();
}
```

As your exception indicated `[[Ljava.lang.Object;@90d0bf]` (which is an Object[]), maybe you should try List<Long> as in my example?

*(p.s. You can use the fluid API of JPA to make your code a little less verbose)*

Comment: it's not Object[], it's List<Long>. I don't do IN on a property on my main Entity, but on an entity that's manyToOne, don't know if it matters.

Comment: I think my problem is because List<Long> gets a List<Object[]>  ... and I have unchecked warning set in Eclipse to not be displayed

Comment: The IN always worked, the problem was that List<Long> wasn't actually List<Long> was List<Object[]>. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The 'IN' clause in hibernate is *very*, *very* tricky, and as far as I remember doesn't play well with named parameters, but it does with positional parameters.

Try changing the query to this

```
@NamedQuery(name = "someName", query = "select x from X x where x.y.id in (?)")
```

and the code that uses it to

```
TypedQuery<X> query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("someName", X.class);
query.setParameter(1, someListOfLongs); // I can't remember if the position is 0 or 1 based.
queryFinal.getResultList();
```

And I should add that if the list is emtpy, you'll get an exception. In our code, we detect this situation and replace the empty list with a list that contains a '-1' and since all ids are positive we don't get any results back.

Comment: I still get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@5625ea] was not matching type [java.lang.Long]`

Comment: The IN always worked, the problem was that List<Long> wasn't actually List<Long> was List<Object[]>. Thanks